# Get the transaction history from Android Pay via API?

Tags: java, android, google-api, android-pay

Our application (an expenses manager) would like to extract the **transaction history** from *Android Pay* in order to make it easier for the user to enter their purchase history. Is this possible - either through an **Android app** on the same phone where the purchases were made or through an **external API**?

I've found plenty of information on how to integrate *Android Pay* payments from within the app, but nothing on how to access the previous transactions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like this is not possible via any API at this moment. It is probably made for security purposes.

The only way to view the transaction history is by:

- Opening the `Android Pay` app.
- Touching the card you used to pay.

But there might be a workaround, though remember that **you are responsible for your actions.**

- Create an [`AccessibilityService`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html)
- Subscribe for [`AccessibilityEvent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent.html) (for example focus on element) using [`onAccessibilityEvent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html#onAccessibilityEvent(android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent))
- Advice user to enable your service in Settings and open the `Android Pay` app.
- Get focused element's text using [`getText()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityRecord.html#getText()) method of an `AccessibilityEvent`
- Pass it to your activity using an [`Intent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Comment: Thanks sudo. I appreciate the workaround but was looking for a more legitimate way to do it. Hopefully Google will open up it's APIs to let users use their own data the way they want.

Comment: @ste_irl - have you found a solution?

Comment: @Etam No I did not. There is a new revised payment directive coming from the EU in 2018. It will force banks to open up their member data to be accessible via APIs. That is the best way forward with this problem.

Comment: @ste_irl do you know the name/number of it?

Comment: @Etam PSD2 is what I am talking about: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Services_Directive#Revised_Directive_on_Payment_Services_(PSD2)

Answer (score 3):

In the EU, the implementation of an API that offers access to banking data is underway and it will involve all banks, Android Pay as a service will have to comply to it.

Here is some articles worth reading:

https://www.scribd.com/doc/298569302/The-Open-Banking-Standard
https://www.mckinsey.com/industries/financial-services/our-insights/data-sharing-and-open-banking

> The European Union is rapidly advancing legislation that will, upon implementation in the next two
> years, require UK banks (subject to consent from individuals and businesses) to open access to their
> customer data and payments capabilities. The UK has diligently fostered a vibrant financial
> technology environment and stands ready to reap the benefits of that legislation sooner than many
> other markets. Other markets (in the EU and beyond) have begun to implement aspects of an open
> banking standard, but none have produced a definitive outline of such a standard, let alone a
> roadmap for its implementation. There is, therefore, a significant opportunity for the UK economy if we
> take a lead in this space. This will require that we invest rigorously in development over the next 6-12
> months.

...

> Regardless of location, over the next 18 to 24 months banks should capitalize on their incumbent advantages by taking the following actions:
>
> - Explore data-sharing agreements with fintech and nonfinancial services firms to stay ahead of the curve.
> - Develop a perspective on APIs and their benefit to the bank’s service
>   model, both in leveraging mandated third-party access and potentially
>   extending access beyond statutory requirements.
> - Fully understand both
>   existing data privacy mandates and likely changes, and determine
>   their institution’s appetite for a less conventional approach. And
>   examine how customer messaging would best facilitate any such change.